# How to maximize matrix products

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, matrix-decomposition, least-squares

Find a unit vector v1 and a unit vector v2, such that the term:

$$v^T \begin{bmatrix} 6 & -2 \\ -2 & 6 \end{bmatrix}v$$

is minimized and maximized, respectively. What are the minimum and maximum values of the above term when v is a unit vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem uses a basic fact about quadratic forms, symmetric matrices and their eigenvalues and eigenvectors, but you don't need to know anything about the latter to solve it. Let $v=(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)^T$. Then the problem becomes that of finding the maxima and minima of $$(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)\pmatrix{6&-2\\-2&6}\pmatrix{\cos\theta\\ \sin\theta}=6\cos^2\theta-4\cos\theta\sin\theta+6\sin^2\theta=6-2\sin{2\theta}$$ on the interval $0\le\theta<2\pi$. You should be able to handle that on your own.

Answer (score 1):

In the symmetric case, the answers are given by the unit eigenvectors with the smallest and largest eigenvalue (respectively). This occurs in your case.

Comment: Could you please explain more!

Comment: @user3687267 What, specifically, do you not understand? Do you want to know why this result holds?

Comment: I don't know where to start can you show me some hint or formula that I can use!

Comment: @user3687267 I just told you what to do: find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. The minimizer will be the eigenvector for the smaller eigenvalue, the maximizer will be the eigenvector for the larger eigenvalue. You can find how to compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors of 2x2 matrices in any linear algebra text, I won't do that part for you.